# @Master declaration giving syntax error

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I've got a master page and I'm trying to declare that it is written in C#.

However when I enter this to the top of the Design.master file it gives "Syntax error".

`<%@ Master Language="C#" %>`

What I don't understand is that Visual Studio is writing the code for me pretty much...

What could be causing this?

[image]

Comment: What is the exact error and where are you seeing it (in the errors window or in the editor?).  There's nothing wrong with that masterpage directive.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I've edited the question with an image of my screen.  The declaration is underlined and when I hover over it shows "Syntax Error.".

Comment: I just closed the tab and reopened and it was ok with it.  Grrr Visual Studio!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I closed the tab and reopened it and the syntax was then validated successfully.

Grrr!